# Need firebase image storage path but storageRef is returning a promise - react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I want to display the list of image stored in firebase in the flatlist but the function is returning promise instead of the url. How can I solve it? I've used async wait in the function. I think it is giving me the promise but if I remove async, it gives null since it takes time to get url from the firebase. I've been trying for a week but cannot solve it. Any help is appreciated. Thankyou

Code:

```
renderList = (item) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ marginBottom: 15, marginLeft: 10 }}>
        <Text>{`Date: ${item.Date}`}</Text>

        {/*
        <Image
            source={{ uri: `${this.getImageUrl(item.FileName)}` }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
        />*/}

        <Text>{`${this.getImageUrl(item.FileName)}`}</Text> //it gives object object
      </View>
    );
}


getImageUrl = async(fileName) => {
    let urll;
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(`${currentUser.uid}/${fileName}.PNG`);
    await storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        urll = url;
        console.log('zzz', url); //it gives valid url
    }, function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
    return urll; //it returns object object (promise)
}

render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={listArray}
          renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderList(item)}
        />
      </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting back an Object because that is what firebase.storage is designed to do. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage.html
You should now be able to inspect the url object returned and access the needed data inside the object.

Comment: The console gives following promise. How to access the path from it?
Promise
_40: 0
_55: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxx.appspot.com/o/zzz%2F1560068528.PNG?alt=media&token=xxxx"
_65: 1
_72: null
__proto__: Object